# How to back transform a folded power transformation?

Tags: back-transformation

I work with a dependent variable with values from 0 to 1 and because I have a lot of 0 and 1 in this variable, i'm doing a folded power transformation with the following formular: y = x^0.5 - (1-x)^0.5. In order to be able to describe the effect strength of the DV in a regression later on, I want to back transform the results of the folded power transformation.

I saw here: [How to back transform a folded root?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/399916/how-to-back-transform-a-folded-root), that @Izy had a similar question. But the formula he gets to back transform the folded power transformation, which is this formula:c=((1−(f(p))2)/2)^2 doesn't work for me. Does anyone know what the problem is or what I am doing wrong? I would be grateful for any advice.