# Forecasting daily data with zeros in Python

Tags: time-series, forecasting, python, prophet

I'm currently testing some forecasts on daily sales quantities. However, out of ~2000 observations I have 16 zeros.

How should I approach this? It's mainly Sundays and holidays that holds zero as value. I want to perform some transformations to the time series that doesn't allow for zeros, why I'm looking for solutions.

Example of data:

```
             Sales_interior
CalendarDate                
2014-01-02       1066.000000
2014-01-03       1735.000000
2014-01-04       2538.000000
2014-01-05        952.000000
2014-01-06       1417.000000
2014-01-07       2205.000000
2014-01-08       1567.000000
2014-01-09       1464.000000
2014-01-10       1636.000000
2014-01-11       1979.000000
2014-01-12          0.000000
2014-01-13       1085.000000
```

EDIT: I'm currently planning on using a seasonal ARIMA.

Comment: If you are using models which allow for variables then you can include dummy variables which indicate holidays (and hence lower then normal or no sales).

Comment: Just edited my question. I'm planning on using a SARIMA.

Comment: In that case you can include variables, at least for some implementations.

Comment: Are these entries zero because they are missing values that defaulted in value to zero?

Comment: Was the store closed on those days? If so, is there any reason why you can't just remove those observations? Furthermore, given that 0 is a physically-permissible number of items sold, I would question the appropriateness of any transformation of the data that can't handle zeros.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is simply to exclude holidays or use a dummy as suggested in the comments. In finance for example, in most cases week-ends are excluded from the time-series. why should we model the sales where we are sure that there can be no sales due to holidays and store closures? The coefficients will be estimated in such a way that they will be constant across all the samples t, so they will be influenced to some extent by the calendar effect, and if you do not adjust for this, that effect will indirectly spill to the coefficient estimates to some extent (i.e. to some extent we could imagine that the true autocorrelation will be underestimated assuming that 0s are several compared to the total number of observations). So why taking into account dates where there cannot be sales for “external, calendar, reasons” not due to the true autocorrelation in the time series? Model this as a calendar effect because it is! So that you can isolate the calendar effect from the conditional mean effect due to time-series autocorrelation and make the estimate of the latter cleaner.

If instead 0 sales are not due to holidays, then my best advice is to leave those 0s, because it is “true information”, or at most treat them as outliers.

Comment: "to exclude holidays"  can work if you are bringing in fixed-effects ( 6 in number) to deal with daily data impact BUT if you are trying to use autoregressive memory things get complicated as the frequency of interval is no longer constant which would argue for interpolated estimates (somehow) .

Comment: I agree with the fact that the length of the interval is no longer constant in theory, but in practice you can simply assume that when there is a holiday it means that there is no business day and therefore no new info on the series. For example consider the financial case, where you study the prices given by the stock exchanges. If the stock exchange is closed then there is no price provided by any exchange. The next observation of the process will be the next price given by the exchange.. in this case it is almost the same: shops are closed so there is nothing new to observe (ie no process)

Comment: So, to avoid problems, let's redefine the process to be observed as "sales for every t, where t denotes business days instead of days" if we are sure that for each non-business day the sales are 0. In this case, the frequency is still constant if expressed as frequency in business days bevause it will be one observation per business day

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be to interpolate the missing observations. One way how to interpolate data in python is to use the scipy.interpolate package. For example, some spline interpolation might nicely fill the gaps.

Of course, interpolating data introduces some potential issues since we don't know what the real sales at that time would have been if the store was open. Moreover, since the store was actually closed the sales were actually zero. You could still combine this approach with the idea of adding a dummy for these days to see if the results are in any way being driven the sales at interpolated dates.

Answer (score -2):

simply add 100 to every observation to make every observation > 0 . Please read [When (and why) should you take the log of a distribution (of numbers)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18844/when-and-why-should-you-take-the-log-of-a-distribution-of-numbers) . Additionally there can be different lead and lag effects around EACH holiday.

Comment: What justifies such an arbitrary recipe?  Where did the value of 100 come from?

Comment: it guarantees all #'s will be > 0 . it could be .001 . it doesn't really make a difference ..it is arbitrary as far as I know ....unless you can cite otherwise from the literature.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195293/what-is-the-most-appropriate-way-to-transform-proportions-when-they-are-an-indep might be of help here

Comment: @IrishStat and simply subtract 100 from the forecasted series afterwards?

Comment: that would work for me ....BUT maybe I have something to learn here ...from @whuber

Comment: I would like to suggest that the analysis I presented at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30749/919 is relevant.  It makes the case that the "start value" of 100 is not arbitrary and its choice matters.